# Call function after highchart is loaded Ember.js

Tags: javascript, function, ember.js

I need to set up all boxes on the same height.
I've done that but I have a problem with highcharts.
It's loading after my function and when all it`s loaded in the boxes I have just a half chart.

How can I call a function after the highcharts is loaded?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    /**
     * Equal heights of each box wrapper
     */
    sameHeight: Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function () {

        let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
        var tallest = 0;

        // Loop over matching and finding tallest
        for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            let elementHeight = boxes[i].offsetHeight; //Get the height and width of a element, including padding and border
            if (elementHeight > tallest) {
                tallest = elementHeight;
            }
        }
        //add same height to all
        var findClass = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
        for (let i = 0; i < findClass.length; i++) {
            findClass[i].style.height = tallest + "px";
        }
    })

});
```

This is a function in Ember Component.

Comment: How do you include highcharts? Can you provide a fill not working code example as a git repository or as ember-twiddle?

Comment: https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/run-loop/

Comment: Run Loop is answer for my problem. Just put instead sameHeight: Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function ()         ->           sameHeight: Ember.run.next('afterRender', function ()

Comment: Thank you Lux for interesting for my problem. :)

Comment: When exactly do you want this code to run? Just once after highcharts is loaded, or every time you render one of these chart components?

Answer (score -1):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    sameHeight: Ember.run.next('afterRender', function () {

        let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
        var tallest = 0;

        // Loop over matching and finding tallest
        for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            let elementHeight = boxes[i].offsetHeight; //Get the height and width of a element, including padding and border
            if (elementHeight > tallest) {
                tallest = elementHeight;
            }
        }
        //add same height to all
        var findClass = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
        for (let i = 0; i < findClass.length; i++) {
            findClass[i].style.height = tallest + "px";
        }
    })

});
```